# RNDIS driver setup missing win 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, windows-7, drivers, intel-edison, driver-signing

Hi I have been trying to connect a few boards to my computer. These boards depend on RNDIS driver to get into concole. So if I connect a board for the first time my Win7 Laptop properly detects it as a RNDIS ethernet adapter or device. But when I plug in the boards second time it just comes up as a unknown device in USB section of device manager. From searching the web I assume that something is RNDIS to fail. So I try to install the driver manually using [`http://www.sharpduino.com/en/articles/article/19`](http://www.sharpduino.com/en/articles/article/19) where it suggest to manually install a driver under `Network Adapters > Microsoft Corporation > RNDIS`. But here is the problem the entire **Microsoft corporation folder in the driver setup is missing**. I am getting no help on the web on why this is so.

And this problem is not just on one board but on others as well. Boards used so far Intel Edison, Arietta G25.

Comment: Where is the programming-related question?

Comment: @frasian I need to get into linux console on the board and that is my problem. I cannot program without getting into console. I want to setup SSH to do this but Win 7 seems to play with setup.

Comment: Yes I have the same issue. the Microsoft Corporation catalog used to be in the driver search dialog, but after some time it's gone. I suspect Windows update removed the driver.